# Data not getting populated in JQuery Datatable

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

I am making an Ajax call and the returned value is stored in "data" variable. Now, I want to use this "data" (in the form of JSON object) to bind the table 'templateRegArea'.

```
$.ajax({
    url: "Ajax_UserPermissionProfile.aspx/GetTemplatePropertyList",
    method: 'post',
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    data: "{ 'iAcctId': '" + $('#hidIAcctId').val() + "', 'iTemplateID': '" + templateID + "'}",

    success: function(response) {
        var data = eval((response.d != undefined) ? response.d : response);
        alert(data);
        $('#templateRegArea').DataTable({
            ajax: data,
            columns: [{
                data: data.ID
            }, {
                data: data.Name
            }, {
                data: null,
                className: "center",
                defaultContent: '<a href="" class="editor_edit">Edit</a> / <a href="" class="editor_remove">Delete</a>'
            }]
        });
    },
    error: function(error) {}
}
```

I am getting the following error.

[image: error]

[image]

Comment: You're getting an "Invalid JSON response". What's the value of that "data"?

Comment: data.ID and data.Name contains some value

Comment: Copy and paste the data here @Roneetshaw

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes datatable expects all the columns to be mapped with the data sent in JSON.

Answer (score 0):

I assume these "ID" and "Name" values are the values you want to put on your table as rows. The "columns" DataTable property expects to get the names of the columns, not its values. From the documentation [example](http://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/object_dom_read.html):

```
$('#example').DataTable({
    "columns": [
        { "data": "name" },
        { "data": "position" },
        { "data": "office" },
        { "data": "age" },
        { "data": "start_date" },
        { "data": "salary" }
    ]
});
```

What you should do is create the columns with `"data": "ID"` and `"data: Name"` and then add those values as rows.

Comment: But how to add the datasource ?

Comment: Add the field "data" to the constructor: http://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/js_array.html